# ASP.Net Azure SignalR Error Failed to ping server. Server responded with status code 401, stopping the connection

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr-hub, azure-signalr

Thanks for help me out from this problem

> We are using this on startup.cs and also a connection string in
> web.config file, could you help me how to stop the message am i getting
> Failed to ping server.  Server responded with status code 401, stopping the connection.
> Couldn't reconnect within the configured timeout of 5000 ms, disconnecting.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)

{
    GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
    GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    GlobalHost.Configuration.DefaultMessageBufferSize = 500;
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Main/Login"),
        CookieName = typeof(Startup).FullName,
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),
            OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
            {
                if (!IsAjaxRequest(ctx.Request))
                {
                    ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                }
            }
        }
    });            
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
    app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
    app.MapAzureSignalR(this.GetType().FullName);
    app.Map("/DetailedErrors", map =>
    {
        HubConfiguration hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
        {
            EnableDetailedErrors = true,
            EnableJavaScriptProxies = false
        };
        map.MapAzureSignalR(this.GetType().FullName, hubConfiguration);
    });
}
```

Comment: are you hosting it in Azure? Ping is disabled by default.

Comment: i am getting more than 1500 error in my log for a day, on production server, please help me out, thanks for helping

Comment: yes, it is hosted on Azure, how to check ping is disabled or not

Comment: Getting i log file, and application slower day by day
Couldn't reconnect within the configured timeout of 5000 ms, disconnecting.
Failed to ping server.  Server responded with status code 401, stopping the connection.

Comment: sorry friend, we cannot help you. This is an error related to your application. 401 means you're not passing an authorization token in the request. I recommend you removing the authorization part, and see if will work again

Comment: @PikuShrivastav Did you find a solution to this?